# Why do I get a gap between my two background images in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I am finding a little compatibility problem of a CSS setting with Chrome browser.

To see the problem you have to open this page both with Firefox (that have no problem) and Chrome (where does the problem occur): http://onofri.org/example/WebTemplate/

So this is a web layout. In the header of this layout there is a green horizontal menu: the **`#nav` div**.

As you can see, it has a background immage, named **right-nav.gif** that represents the right "side" of the menu

Then the internal **ul list** that represent the menu have a background immage, named **left-nav.gif** that represent the left "side** of the menu

Finally all the internal **li tag** that represent the voices into my menu have a background immage, named **bg-nav.gif**.

The problem is that when I open it using Chrome browser, a little space appears between the **left-nav.gif** image and the first **bg-nav.gif** immage.

The problem occur only at some magnification (using the key combination CTRL +)

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is something missing in your question. I guess a link.

Comment: OMG, I have edited and I have insert the link to my layout

Comment: That is an absolute normal behavior. When you manify a bit more, then you see that the little space goes away. That happens quite often when images are used. Every browser calculates the pixels in its own way and also behaves different on sizes that are a fraction of a pixel.

Comment: @Sven Biender mmm and exist a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: It should work if you give your first li a `margin-left:-1px;`. That solves the problem with the half pixel.

Comment: I would make a single image for the menu background with repeat-x and use border-radius for the corners, also you may want to try using css for the gradient as well, check http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for a quick gradient generator tool

Comment: @koala_dev That is nice as long as it doesn't need to work in IE8 and former

Comment: @SvenBieder yes, but generally gradients and rounded corners should serve more of an aesthetic purpose so you shouldn't need to worry too much about the support from older browsers